# Dynamically Modifying a LINQ to SQL Select Statement's Columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to build a REST-ful API for my app. Currently I have something like this:
`www.example.com/submissions/?format=json`

This will return latest ten submissions in JSON. Each object has its details, such as submission name, date created, user, body, etc.

I'd like to do something such as:
`www.example.com/submissions/?format=json&filter=name,user`

The filter should make the request to return the same result but to only include the details mentioned, i.e. each object will only have a name and user.

This is fairly straightforward in terms of the JSON output. I can load all the columns from the database and create and serialize an object that will only include the columns in the filter. However, I do not want to load all the columns in the database - **I want to bother my database with only the columns that I will include in the response**.

I want to do something like this:

```
var result = from record in Submissions
             select
             {
                Name,
                Date,
                User,
                Body
             };
```

Now I have the `result` object, which is IQueryable, so no call to database made yet.

Then, I should examine the `filter` querystring and exclude the columns that are not mentioned.

Finally, I can execute the select statement with something like
`JavaScript.Serialize(result.ToList());`

Is this possible with LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to building your Select expression tree by hand is [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), which provides a `Select` method that takes a string:

```
var filter = "name,user";
var result = Submissions.Select("new(" + filter + ")");
```

The string is then translated into an expression tree and passed on to your query provider.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are going to want to research [Modifying Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx). Specifically the [MemberInit Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344570.aspx).