# LINQ to SQL variable number of columns for Select

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to set up my program such that I can perform a LINQ query to my database, and have it only grab columns that the user is wishing to show.  Whether a column is to be shown or not is determined by a True/False value associated with that column that is stored inside of a `.ini` file that is being used to store user data.

I am currently having trouble setting up my LINQ query to facilitate this.

```
Dim query = (From p in dbContext.Parts)
If GetINI("DB_Parts_Columns", "Part_Number", "True") Then
    query.Select(Function(x) x.Part_Number)
End If
If GetINI("DB_Parts_Columns", "Manufacturer", "True") Then
    query.Select(Function(x) x.Part_Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name)
query.Take(100)
dataGrid.DataSource = query
```

EDIT: A quick note about the `GetINI` method.  The first two parameters are where the program is suppose to be looking for the value in the file (a `True/False` value), and the third parameter is the default value to be set if there is no matching data in the `.ini` file.

My code looks like the above, with a bunch more `If/End If` statements for each column.  I thought this would set up a statement similar to something like

```
Dim query = (From p In dbContext.Parts
             Select p.Part_Number)
```

However, when I setup a simple `MessageBox.Show` to view what the query looks like, well let's just say while I am not getting any errors, the query is doing nothing.  The resulting query I end up getting is just a query that is essentially `SELECT * FROM Parts`, though it doesn't actually give me any data for my `DataGridView`.

Is there a way to setup a LINQ query where you can determine what it is you are going to be selecting after some  `If/End If` statements?

EDIT: Changing the lines within the `If/End If` statements to:

```
query = query.Select(Function(x) x.Part_Number)
```

Give me the following error:

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Database_App.Part]'
```

Comment: I think you are missing how the LINQ methods you are calling are supposed to work.  Your calls to .Select and .Take are not doing what you think they are.  If you aren't going to chain the methods together, you have to explicitly set the return value on query...so instead of query.Select(blah), you need to reset your query variable like this:  query = query.Select(blah).

Comment: @user1011627 Thanks for the heads up.  I can't believe I was forgetting that.  However after changing it to `query = query.Select(Function(x) x.Part_Number)` I am getting a `InvalidCastException` error :\

Comment: Normally when using an ORM, you are filtering **rows**, not *columns* - the point being that an object (the O in ORM) always has all those members. There are some slight exceptions for large fields (CLOBs/BLOBs), but... OK - can I clarify? Why do you want to filter the *columns* here? I wonder if perhaps an ORM simply isn't a good fit for this query. And *that's OK* - it is OK to use different tools in different places - so an ORM in one place, a micro-ORM in another, and ad-hoc data access somewhere else. All fine.

Comment: I think the OP's goal is to dynamically select fields from the object, not filter by them.  I don't know VB.NET so I'm not entirely sure what "Function(x) x.Part_Number" is doing in this context.  In C#, you would likely see a lambda expression selecting which fields so I assume this is VB's counterpart to lambda.

Comment: @user1011627 Yes, `Function(x) x.Part_Number` translates to `x => x.Part_Number`.

Comment: LINQ is designed for static querying/typing, as the whole point is to have the compiler understand the types available. Dynamically adjusting the returned columns is far outside it's intent, however it is possible with some very complicated code. As pointed out above, better to not go that route. Also, are you returning enough data that it is worth reducing the network traffic by narrowing to a few columns?

Comment: @Skitzafreak - Scott Guthrie has a good blog post about dynamic queries using LINQ and Microsoft has already done the hard work for you by creating a dynamic LINQ library which exposes a customized Select method to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Read Scott's blog post and review this other SO question and it should put you on the right track if you want to use LINQ to accomplish this.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821558/dynamically-modifying-a-linq-to-sql-select-statements-columns
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb964686.aspx

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented, currently parsing all the advice here. @MarcGravell, to answer your question of why I want to filter columns here, essentially I am creating a datatable for, in my example above, entries in the Parts Table of a database.  The user is able to choose which pieces of data they want to view, for example the Part Number, the Supplier, the Description, etc.  So I am trying to filter by column to allow the user to have this level of customization in the data they see.

Comment: @Skitzafreak unless you have especially wide data, you'd be better off making that decision at the UI layer, not the data access layer

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, thank you.  It kind of hit me how I should be implementing this, as opposed to how I was thinking of implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was going about my problem the wrong way.  Instead of trying to modularize the data I was trying to access, I should have instead been modularizing the data I was trying to *show*.

The following code does what I was attempting to accomplish.

```
Public Sub GetTable(ByRef dataGrid As DataGridView, tblName As String)
    Using dbContext As New Data_LINQDataContext
        Select Case tblName
            Case "Parts"
                Dim query = (From p In dbContext.Parts
                             Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, p.Part_Information, _
                             p.Supplier.Supplier_Name, p.Part_Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name, _
                             p.Part_Subcategory.Part_Category.Category_Description, _
                             p.Part_Subcategory.Subcategory_Description).Take(250)
                dataGrid.DataSource = query
                For Each col As DataGridColumn In dataGrid.Columns
                    col.Visible = GetINI("DB_Parts_Columns", col.Name, "True")
                    col.Width = GetINI("DB_Parts_Columns_Width", col.Name, "150")
                Next
        End Select
    End Using
End Sub
```

Thank you to anyone who commented on the OP with helpful advice, it is what led me to concluding that this is the implementation I was looking for.